# Tcl program to print file name when executed from another script

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script say a.tcl which is executed by another tcl script b.tcl.
I want to print the name of a.tcl.How to do that??

Answer (score 1):

The name of the currently executing script is provided by the `info script` command. That reports whatever was passed to `source` or the invoke of `tclsh` (it's actually whatever is given to the `Tcl_EvalFile` — or related API — call). If you need the *full* filename, use it with `file normalize`.

The full recipe is:

```
puts [file normalize [info script]]
```

Note that the result of `info script` is only useful while the script is *actually* running, and not necessarily when the procedures it creates are running.